Prove the following result using integration in 2D.
A segment is cut off from a sphere of radius $a$ by a plane at a distance $a/2$ from the centre. Show that the volume of the segment is $5/32$ of the volume of the sphere.
Now, I already know how to do this in 3D using cylindrical coordinates.
Suppose equation of plane is -
$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ where a is the radius of the sphere.
Now, assume the plane $z = a/2$ cuts off the sphere.
Substitute $x = r\cos\theta$
$y = r\sin\theta $
We can rewrite the sphere as -
$ r^2 + z^2 = a^2$
Volume will be -
V = $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{a/2}^a \int_0^{\sqrt {a^2-z^2}} r dr dz d\theta$
Upon integrating, we will get
V = $5/24 \pi a^3$
But, how do we do this in 2D?
Equation of circle will be $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$.
Equation of line will be $ x + y = a/2 $
We solve for intersection points.
V =$\pi \int_a^b y^2 dx$ where a and b are the intersection points.
My doubt is, in my textbook it is specifically asking me to solve this in 2D. But, intersection points are irrational numbers, even if I take $y = a/2$ or $x = a/2$, calculations are very exhausting, and I am not able to arrive at my answer.
Please suggest some method to solve this.

Surely the area of the segment is $\int_{-x_0}^{x_0} ( \sqrt{a^2-x^2} - {a \over 2}) dx$, where $x_0^2+ ({a \over 2})^2 = a^2$.

@copper.hat yes. but i need the volume, not area.

What would volume mean in 2D?

@copper.hat hmm. area * length? so i should compute the length of the segment too? and then multiply them. makes sense. but how should i do this using the formula mentioned above?

I believe that the idea is to consider the polar cap's height above the slicing plane as a function of position on the slicing plane.
So you're going to integrate over the disk defined by $x^2 + y^2 \le \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$ (albeit in the plane $z = a/2$, but that doesn't matter to the integral!) with the integrand being the distance from $z = a/2$ upwards to the surface of the original sphere.

i didn't quite get it. can you elaborate a bit more?

Slice off the top of the sphere with the plane $z = a/2$, like slicing off the top of a boiled egg. You want to find the volume of that "cap", right? The entire cap lies above the disk $x^2 + y^2 \le (a/2)^2$. Does that seem OK to you? Let's look at a point of that disk, like $(0,0)$. There's a line segment in the "cap" lying above the point. For $(0,0)$, that line segment goes from $(0,0,a/2)$ to $(0,0,a)$. So its length is $a/2$. For each $(x,y)$ in the disk, there's a similar line segment (but with a different length). You want to "add them all up" to get the volume, i.e., integrate.
